What tags are Bitcoin specific and shouldn't be confused with Ripple? (and vice versa)
I want to avoid the overloading of terms that are common between Ripple vs Bitcoin, and think this may effect the tags on this site.
What tags need to be updated to reflect the difference?

"transactions" comes to mind.

@NickODell why?

@ripper234 Because you can have Ripple transactions, and Bitcoin transactions.

@NickODell - so? I don't think that this is reason enough to have two different tags.

@ripper234 I was stating the term was shared, not that I thought it ought to be split.
